# How can I take a decision based on a type within a macro?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++11, macros, code-generation

In my company, I'm working on providing a faster SSE path for some hot code. I'm using the intrinsic approach which keeps to C++ and really shows impressive results.

All code only has to work on `float` and `double`, so I created a templated SSE operations class that I specialized for both. What I really don't like is that these two classes look almost identical except for the number type (`float`/`double`), the used SSE type (`__m128`/`__m128d`) and the intrisics suffix (`_ps`/`_pd`) like so:

```
template<>
struct SseOperations<float> : public Sse<float>
{
    typedef __m128 vector;

    vector load(float const * const from) const
    {
        return _mm_loadu_ps(from);
    }

    vector add(vector const & a, vector const & b) const
    {
        return _mm_add_ps(a, b);
    }

    // etc.
};
```

and

```
template<>
struct SseOperations<double> : public Sse<double>
{
    typedef __m128d vector;

    vector load(double const * const from) const
    {
        return _mm_loadu_pd(from);
    }

    vector add(vector const & a, vector const & b) const
    {
        return _mm_add_pd(a, b);
    }

    // etc.
};
```

I wouldn't know how to unify this using template magic, because of the different intrinsics suffix.

Then the `##` capability of macros came to my mind, which would lend itself for that purpose. So I managed to put the complete specialized class into a macro that I could use to generate both classes with:

```
SSE_OPERATIONS(float, __m128, _ps);
SSE_OPERATIONS(double, __m128d, _pd);
```

I know macros are evil and all, but at least in this case I don't see any of the typical dangers and it gets the job done.

What bothers me now is that the second and third macro parameter are redundant; they could be deduced from the first one, only that I have absolutely no idea how. `#if` and its friends aren't supposed to work because `sizeof()` doesn't work during pre-processing.

Searching for solutions is unexpectedly hard, because of `#if` topics polluting the results heavily. Can anyone tell me how to do a macro level decision for this problem?

PS: I heard of [Boost Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) but I'm not allowed to use it.

**Update:** Although I'm asking for a macro solution, I would also accept a nice template solution. For that, know that I'm encapsulating at least 7 intrinsics—just in case that would bloat template code.

Comment: If you could do this with the macro, you could do it without the macro just as well.

Comment: I don't see how the macro parameters are redundant. The 3 names are entirely unrelated at token level. Your macro must by necessity state the logical relation between those 3 tokes. You just can't deduce `_ps` from ` float`. Of course, this ultimately is caused by the extremely limited integration of SSE primitives and C++. If the responsible compiler developer had understood both, he'd have realized that `operator+` is a perfectly sane name for `_mm_add_pd`. Operator overloading is decades old; no need to keep imposing assembler limitations on programs today.

Comment: Ok, they're not redundant to the PP, but to me. If I had a macro if, I could just compute/set them at the beginning of the macro given only `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the second parameter by a trait:

```
template <class Scalar>
struct Vector;

template <>
struct Vector<float>
{
  typedef __m128 type;
};

template <>
struct Vector<double>
{
  typedef __m128d type;
};
```

As for the third one, you can do a really <s>ugly</s> special preprocessor <s>hack</s> trick:

```
#define SUFFIX_float ps
#define SUFFIX_double pd
```

and use `##` on `SUFFIX_` and the outermost macro parameter to arrive at the correct version. Of course, it would require some levels of indirection to get the macros to expand at the correct time. Using [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), in particular `BOOST_PP_CAT` and possibly `BOOST_PP_EXPAND`, might make this slightly easier.